# Typescript2: Array<any> and Array<Object> difference

Tags: typescript

Which is the difference between declaring a field as `Array<any>` and `Array<Object>`.

Is there some extra collection tools in typescript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `Object` in TypeScript is the same thing as in JavaScript.

The difference is that `any` accepts primitives as well: a `number` is not an object, unless boxed to a `Number`.

So while an `Array<any>` can contain primitives, an `Array<Object>` can't.

TL;DR: don't use `Object`.

Source: [TypeScript's Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html)

Answer (score 3):

You are basically asking what's the difference between `any` and `Object` and that's answered in the [docs about `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any):

> The any type is a powerful way to work with existing JavaScript,
>   allowing you to gradually opt-in and opt-out of type-checking during
>   compilation. **You might expect Object to play a similar role, as it
>   does in other languages**. But variables of type Object only allow you
>   to assign any value to them - you can’t call arbitrary methods on
>   them, even ones that actually exist:

```
let notSure: any = 4;
notSure.ifItExists(); // okay, ifItExists might exist at runtime
notSure.toFixed(); // okay, toFixed exists (but the compiler doesn't check)

let prettySure: Object = 4;
prettySure.toFixed(); // Error: Property 'toFixed' doesn't exist on type 'Object'.
```

Answer (score 2):

`Object` is the root type for classes and therefore has no properties, except for the inherent properties defined on `Object.prototype`.

`any` is a dynamic type and will compile no matter what properties you access on it.

For example:

```
const a: Object = "Object"
a.length // ERROR

const b: any = "Any"
b.length // Compiles
```

Comment: Well actually Object does have its inherent properties... I understand what you meant but it might be confusing for some.